# How to convert javascript array to a python dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, python-2.7, flask

I want to try to make a little webserver where you can put location data into a database using a grid system in Javascript. I've found a setup that I really liked and maked an example in CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGxEaj. A user can click in a grid to point out the location. In the console log I see the data that is generated as output. For every cell in the grid it has a dictionary that looks like this:

```js
click: 4
height: 50
width: 50
x: 1
xnum: 1
y: 1
ynum: 1
```

A complete overview of output data looks like this, where their are 10 arrays for every row, 10 arrays for every column of that row, and then a dictionary with the values:
[image]

Now i want to get this information back to python in a dictionary as well, so i can store particular information in a database. But I can't figure out what the best way is to do that. Hopefully you could provide a little push in the right direction, links to usefull pages or code snippets to guide me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with javascript. You just need to look into parsing json in Python, https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

Comment: json stringify on js/ client side and json module on python/ server side maybe

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by converting your JS object into JSON:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myJsObj);
```

And then converting your Python object to JSON:

```
import json
myPythonObj = json.loads(json)
```

More information about the JSON package for Python can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) and more information about converting JS objects to and from JSON can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the python [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Here is how you can perform such operation using the module.

```
import json
json_data = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}'
loaded_json = json.loads(json_data)
```